# Connecting to VPN prevents access to local machines

Tags: networking, vpn

Let me start off this question by stating that although I know a fair ammount about computer networks in general, I know absolutly nothing about the operation of VPNs. I genuinely have no idea how they work.

I ran into a problem recently while using a VPN. This VPN had been provided to me to be able to use (access via remote desktop) my machine at work, which remains on site.

Once I have connected to the VPN, I am not longer able to access machines on my own personal local network. I assume this is because the "local network" becomes the "local network in the office at work" once I have connected to the VPN.

Is it possible for me to remote desktop into one of my actual local machines as well as remote desktop into the machine I have at work, once I have connected to the VPN?

The machine I am using to establish these connections is a Windows 10 machine, but I have both windows and linux machines on my own local network.

Comment: 'Is it possible for me to remote desktop into one of my actual local machines as well as remote desktop into the machine I have at work, once I have connected to the VPN?" - Only if the VPN has been configured to allow it.

Comment: You need split tunnel VPN to do what you are trying to do.

Comment: What VPN software are you using? Split-tunnel wouldn't be necessary for the local subnet (as it's a higher priority route than the VPN's "default" route), but some VPN clients _deliberately_ block LAN communications -- e.g. Cisco AnyConnect has a checkbox in client settings.

Comment: I configued the VPN using Windows VPN settings. Cisco Anyconnect might be involved in the process somehow, as I have it installed, but it just opens the windows vpn config when I click manage VPN...